# Using Combobox (WinForm) with DataSouce. How to choose which property to show?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am using a ComboBox to show some object from a List. But it is showing the items using the `toString()`method. How can I choose the property i want to be displayed

Comment: Which "property" of the object do you want to show?

Comment: Use **DisplayMember** : `combobox.DisplayMember = "Property_You_Want"`

Comment: the Dni (defined as `public String Dni { get { ... } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for [DisplayMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of ComboBox?

Answer (score 2):

Say you have a list, for example, `List<MyObject>` where `MyObject` is defined as follows:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then you would want to use the **DisplayMember** property as follows:

```
var list = new List<MyObject>();
list.Add(new MyObject { Number = 1, Name = "Char" });
list.Add(new MyObject { Number = 2, Name = "Amuro" });
comboBox1.DataSource = list;
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

Here is an example of how that would output:

[image]